# Function definition not found?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to define the function "getCurSize" but for some reason even though I define it below it, it is not recognizing the definition and is underlined in green. (Beginner here so patience appreciated)

```
template<class ItemType>
class FDHPolynomial
{
private:
    FDHNode<ItemType>* headPtr;
    int itemcount;
    FDHNode<ItemType>* getPointedTo(const ItemType& nodenum) const;

public:
    FDHPolynomial();
    FDHPolynomial(const FDHPolynomial <ItemType>& aPoly);
    virtual ~FDHPolynomial();

    int getCurSize() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool add(const ItemType& newCoeffi, const ItemType& newExpon);
    bool remove(const ItemType& anExpon);
    void clear();
    bool contains(const ItemType& aExpon) const;
    ItemType degree() const;
    ItemType coefficient(const ItemType& power) const;
    void changeCoefficient(const ItemType& newCoeffi, const ItemType&power);
    std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const;

void print();


};

template<class ItemType>
int Polynomial<ItemType>::getCurSize() const
{
    return itemCount;
}
```

Comment: `Polynomial<ItemType>::getCurSize()` -> `FDHPolynomial<ItemType>::getCurSize()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your scope operator (::) cannot match `Polynomial<ItemType>::getCurSize() const` to any function declared, because `Polynomial` does not exist as a class. Because class `FDHPolynomial` has a `getCurSize() const` function, change your definition to this:

```
template<class ItemType>
int FDHPolynomial<ItemType>::getCurSize() const {
    return itemCount;
}
```

Comment: Wow wow wow! I'm smacking my own forehead for that. Thank you that was the issue.